# Visual Studio Code Handlebars Formatting in YAML breaks syntax

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting, yaml

I have a YAML file for helm that got go template style handlebars `{{ .Values.domain }}` however the formatter turns them into `{ { .Values.domain } }` how can I disable specific behavior.

FYI: The setting "Yaml › Format: Bracket Spacing
Print spaces between brackets in objects" is the result `{{.Values.domain}}` is not valid go template syntax.

This behavior is happening with both formatters I have in VSCode
prettier-vscode and redhat-developer/vscode-yaml. I have found out that vscode-yaml is using prettier underneeth.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check VSC settings for "space non-empty braces" (I don't remember the exact name of the setting, hence the search).
2. Make sure it is unchecked.
3. Set the default formatter for your file type to VSCode, not any formatting extension.

Comment: FYI: The setting "Yaml › Format: Bracket Spacing Print spaces between brackets in objects" is the result {{.Values.domain}} is not valid go template syntax.

Comment: That might be worth an issue in the VS code repository

Comment: Is there even such a thing as a VSCode-provided YAML formatter?

Answer (score 0):

I created `~/.prettierignore` file, added *.yaml, *.yml to it, then updated vscode User setting `"prettier.ignorePath": "~/.prettierignore"`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding the following code into settings.json

```
"[helm]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": false
  }
```

For open settings.json use the shortcut command `⌘` + `shift` + `P` for mac, for windows use `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`P`.